# How to add the text from Google Input Tools - Gujarati language

Tags: xetex

I would like to add Text from http://www.google.com/intl/en/inputtools/cloud/try/ . It is an IME Tool where you can write in Gujarati language.

I would like to copy+paste "સહજ ને કિનારે" from Google cloud tool

I have tried using xeLatex, but I am getting output as

Is there any way to copy+paste from Google cloud tool to produce latex.

Thanks.

Regards,
Raval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with Xetex, but if you can use pdflatex or xelatex, then you can use this method. If you don't have the font I used, you can use Arial Unicode MS and it will typeset (the glyphs might change a bit in their appearance).

[image: gujarati]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Gujarati Sangam MN} % or alternatively you can use {Arial Unicode MS}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}\huge

    સહજ ને કિનારે

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Alenanno, I don't know how to say "Thank You".. You have really helped me a lot. I have no words for your help... Really really thankful to you for your kind help. I am compiling some nice articles and was not able to move an inch... Now I am able to move the mountain with your small help... Thanks a ton...